# R tapply() does not work on data.frame due to improper length check

Tags: r, dataframe, tapply

This is a bug report, not a question. The procedure to report bugs in R core appears complicated, and I don't want to be part of a mailing list. So I'm posting this here (as recommended by https://www.r-project.org/bugs.html.)

Here it is:

The `tapply()` help of R 4.0.3 says the following on argument `X`:

> an R object for which a split method exists. Typically vector-like, allowing subsetting with [.

Issue: this R object cannot be a data.frame, although a data.frame can be split and subsetted.

To reproduce, run the following:

```
func <- function(dt) {
    sum(dt[,1] * dt[,2])
}

tab <- data.frame(x = sample(100), y = sample(100), z = sample(letters[1:10], 100, T))

tapply(tab[,1:2], INDEX = tab$z, FUN = func)
```

This results in

> error in tapply(tab[, 1:2], INDEX = tab$z, FUN = func) :
> arguments must have same length

which, upon looking at the `tapply()`source code, appears to result from this check:

```
 if (!all(lengths(INDEX) == length(X))) 
        stop("arguments must have same length")
```

But `length()` is not the relevant function to call on a data.frame to determine if it has the right dimension for a split. `nrow()` should be used instead.

replacing the above code with

```
  if(is.data.frame(X)) {
     len <- nrow(X)
  } else {
        len <- length(X)
  }
  if (!all(lengths(INDEX) == len)) 
        stop("arguments must have same length")
```

solves the error.

This fix looks rather straightforward, and implementing it would increase the usefulness of `tapply()` by a lot (I know there are powerful alternatives to `tapply()`), so I wonder if the current limitation reflects a design choice.

Comment: `length` on a data.frame context is `ncol`.  The function showed above is more suited for `by` and not for `tapply`.

Answer (score 1):

Based on the function, we could use

```
library(dplyr)
tab %>% 
     group_by(z) %>%
     summarise(new = func(cur_data()), .groups = 'drop')
```

-output

```
# A tibble: 10 x 2
#   z       new
#   <chr> <int>
# 1 a     26647
# 2 b     28010
# 3 c     31340
# 4 d     20780
# 5 e     33311
# 6 f     31880
# 7 g     37527
# 8 h      8752
# 9 i     15490
```

---

Or using `by` from `base R`

```
by(tab[, 1:2], tab$z, FUN = func)
```

---

According to `?tapply`

> X - an R object for which a split method exists. Typically vector-like, allowing subsetting with [.

Here, the `tab[, 1:2]` is a data.frame and not a `vector`.  If it is a `matrix`, it would be a `vector` with `dim` attributes

Comment: Ok, so it seems that `by()` is the `tapply()`equivalent for data.frames. But why not make `tapply` work on data.frame ?

Comment: @jeanlain the constraint is the way you created your function which is not the way the `tapply` expects

Comment: @jeanlain it is not a bug as you mentioned.  If you check the `?tapply`, it expects `X` as a vector and your function expects as a data.frame

Comment: `tapply` does not expect `X` to be a data.frame, which is unrelated to the function I'm applying. I'm wondering about the point of this limitation.

Comment: @jeanlain Here, the X is `tab[1:2]` which is a data.frame and your function takes the argument as data.frame.  Not clear about your comment

Comment: I don't see where it's stated that `tapply` expects a vector. The help says it expects an object that can be split. And indeed, my simple fix makes it work on a data.frame.

Comment: @jeanlain `X - an R object for which a split method exists. Typically vector-like, allowing subsetting with [.`

Comment: So I guess the issue stems from the "typically" of the help file. But again, my fix makes the function work on data.frame. So why this limitation?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/222873/discussion-between-jeanlain-and-akrun).